# Função OnChange no Javascript, só funciona com TAB no Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3

Boa noite.

Tenho um formulário bootstrap com modal que ao ser inserido os valores, o calculo só é realizado após dar um TAB pra mudar de campo.

Mas fazendo o teste aqui, funiona com TAB e clicando com o mouse noutro campo.
Não entendo porque no Bootstrap com Modal só funciona com TAB.

Vocês sabem como posso corrigir isso?

```js
$("#percentualDesconto").change(function () {
                    var valor = $("#valor_compra").val();
                    var valorDesconto = valor * (parseFloat($(this).val()) / 100);
                    var valorArrendodado = parseFloat(valorDesconto.toFixed(2));
                    $(".desconto").val(valorArrendodado);
                    var Valor1 = parseFloat($('.desconto').val());
                    var Valor1Arrendodado = parseFloat(Valor1.toFixed(2));

                    var resultadoFinal = valor - Valor1Arrendodado;
                    if (Number.isNaN(resultadoFinal)) {
                        TotFR = 0;
                        $('#valor_desconto').val(resultadoFinal.toFixed(2));
                    } else {
                        $('#valor_desconto').val(resultadoFinal.toFixed(2));
                    }
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">                                        
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                            <label for="valor_compra">Valor Compra</label>                                 
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valor_compra" name="valor" value="0.00"  >
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                            <label for="percentualDesconto">Desconto(%)</label>                                
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control " name="percentualDesconto" value="0.00" id="percentualDesconto" title="Informe o percentual"  size="15" maxlength="25" placeholder="0.00 %"  >
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                            <label for="desconto">Desconto</label>                                 
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control desconto" id="desconto" name="desconto" value="0.00" readonly >
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                            <label for="valor_desconto">Valor Final </label>                                 
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valor_desconto" name="valorComDesconto" value="0.00" readonly >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite, me desculpem, removi a biblioteca maskMoney: https://plugins.jquery.com/maskMoney/

E agora funciona, vou só estudar uma solução pra evitar que o usuário coloque "virgula" ao invés de "ponto".

Comment: Tudo funcionando agora. Estava usando a versão 2.1.2 do MaskMoney e atualizei para a última. Me desculpem, por abrir a questão. Se o moderador quiser remover a pergunta, não tem problema. Obrigada

Comment: Marque a sua resposta.